# Word for the typical posture of a smartphone user

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

A sentence taken from a student's piece of homework.

> I often happen to watch youngsters leaning simultaneously on their smartphones while they are in groups.

[image: People on their phones]

You can understand what he's saying can't you? It's also grammatical. But you don't ‘physically’ lean on a smartphone, do you?

It's a common enough phenomenon in today's society; we have all seen groups of teenagers *huddled over* their smartphones. But what about **leaning**? What preposition do I use with *lean* that fits with the meaning my student wanted to convey?

Do you lean *over* a smartphone?
Do you lean *above* it?
Do you lean *forward*?
That last one sounds OK, but where would you place the noun, smartphone, in the phrase?

I suggested **huddled over** but is there a better or a more appropriate verb I could have suggested?

Comment: I can see it being used in the figurative sense where they're leaning on their smartphones as in being dependent on them for what...entertainment? fitting in with the other students?

Comment: "hunched over"?

Comment: @Josh61 more or less, I think my student wanted to convey the lack of eye contact between these young people, everyone is focussed on their display screens.

Comment: I think your "student" is either nns or not very articulate. You're quite right that *huddled* (or ***hunched over** [their phones]* would be more normal. When you  *lean **on*** [something], that usually implies [something] is providing physical or metaphorical *support*, which doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers well of course he's Italian, the expression stood out, I think he might have been inspired by the leaning tower of Pisa! But overall, it's quite a good sentence.

Comment: I dunno...I think to a native speaker, leaning would imply requiring support and it doesn't sound like that's what the student meant.  Leaning, in the sense of the body being at an angle, brings a picture to mind that is not the one I think of when picturing someone using their smartphone.  It's more like their body is more or less upright but their *heads* are bowed over their hand (with phone) which is held at chest level usually.

Comment: It's perfectly fine for a writer to use a "new" metaphor to describe some phenomenon if the meaning is clear to the reader and the analogy is appropriate.  While there may be better descriptive phrases to use, I seen nothing wrong with that one.

Comment: Yours is probably a more appropriate one. Slouch is a good suggestion, though.

Comment: I leaned on my iPhone 6 ... And it bent. (True story)

Comment: @Stan  :) I've heard that it's a common complaint, am I right? Still, good line, made me smile. Thanks!

Comment: @Mari-LouA yep, it's a sad story for many iPhone 6 users XD

Comment: The picture is nice, but there are no smartphones in it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k erm... lol! Try looking for an image of teenagers, in a group, not talking to each other, but  intent on looking down on their smartphone at the same time. I got 5/6 :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, the picture is illustrative of your question, no doubt. You should have photoshopped it...

Comment: The **iAddict**?

Comment: *"my student wanted to convey the lack of eye contact between these young people, everyone is focussed on their display screens"* - for this aspect, I'd suggest *absorbed in their smartphones*, or *plugged into their smartphones*.  Did I understand right, that for your question you wanted to focus on the body position primarily?

Comment: Yes, he deliberately used "leaned", he would know the term *concentrated* or *absorbed*, he is an advanced level speaker and he's very good.

Comment: Several comments have already noted that “leaning on” can mean “depend on, be dependent on” and I think your Student, whether intentionally or not, hit the nail on the head with “leaning … on their phones” in this sense (maybe only youngsters are addicted to their phones in Italy but here in central Va. even most oldsters are so afflicted). For those who refuse to admit that they’re addicted to anything, there’s the somewhat less fitting [“lean **into**”](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lean-into.2087312/) which can mean: “1. to do or say sometime to an extreme” or 2. “to do it ‘big’.”

Answer (score 11):

The actual physical posture, without imputing any behavior or moral characteristic to it, is "hunched".  It often takes the preposition "over".

> There are a bunch of kids hunched over their smartphones; I don't know if they're texting or playing a game.
>
> While we're visiting your grandparents, I don't want to see you hunch over your phone.
>
> Why is Jim all hunched over?  I don't know - did he hurt his back?

[Hunch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hunched) (MW intransitive verb, definition 2a)

> to assume a bent or crooked posture

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it should be ***"[slouched](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slouch)*** over their smartphones", because "leaning on their smartphones" doesn't make sense, you can't lean over your smartphone. When you are leaning on something, you are leaning on a wall or something, therefore, leaning over is more like bending over/tilting over. Slouched is more like bending, but not a lot.

(M-W)

Comment: ^ because when you are leaning on something, you are leaning on a wall or something, leaning over is more like bending over/tilting over. slouched is more like bending, but not a lot.

Comment: "Lean on" makes perfect sense in its figurative sense of "Rely on".

Answer (score 5):

***[bent over](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bend_1)***

> If you bend your head or if it bends, you move it forward and downward without moving your body downward: *The three of them sat there with their heads bent over their books.*

*(Macmillan Dictionary)*

Your sentence:

> I often happen to watch youngsters bent simultaneously over their smartphones while they are in groups.

Comment: "bowed over" is a close alternative to this that might be worth including -- indicating intense concentration, like pouring over a book.

Comment: The advantage of "heads bent" is that it is accurate, versatile, and less judgmental. People reading their phones bow their heads out of necessity, but it is not true to say they are always "hunched" (about the shoulders") or invariably "slouched" (poor posture). Those negative descriptions allow us to implicitly critique behavior we disapprove of by implying it indicates bad habits and poor self-control. If four youths in identical poses to the OP photo were holding novels instead of phones, would we say slouched? "I can't stand those readers, always slouching over their books in the park!"

Answer (score 2):

Seinfeld called it "the blackberry head-down", which could be updated to "the smartphone head-down".  Although he was referring specifically to the discourteous phenomenon of someone gravitating toward their phone mid-conversation, it could still apply to someone engaged in said posture.  Here's a suggestion- just call it "the phone zone".  i.e. "I just walked by a bunch of teens unnoticed because they were all in the phone zone."  or "He didn't really pay attention to the lecture.  He was in the phone zone."  "A great example of the increased isolationism in modern society is when you see a group of teens hanging out together, but they are all in the phone zone."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the word "cradle" as in, "I often happen to watch youngsters cradling their smartphones while they are in groups."

The literal definition of "to hold or support protectively" works plus it implies the importance of the phone to the typical teen.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't we simply use '**buried themselves in their smartphones**' if you wan't to convey the lack of eye contact between the young people, as you've mentioned.
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bury

Comment: I like the suggestion, but it doesn't really convey their physical posture, although having one's  *head* buried deep in books is very evocative. And to be buried in something almost implies an imposition.

Answer (score -1):

*Cringe upon*? "The teens cringed upon their smartphones." I guess *hunch upon* would work as well: "The teens hunched upon their smartphones."

Sometimes people stand up straight and look at their phones, so stalking would work as well.

Comment: What dialect of English does this represent?

Comment: None of these examples make sense to me in the American English I'm familiar with -- I didn't think you could cringe *upon* or hunch *upon* anything, although I suppose you can huddle *over* something like a fire. If someone said "The people were stalking their phones" I would have no idea what they were talking about.